# Fetching All Items with DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get all of the records from a Dynamo DB table and have them mapped into an array of POJOs; The POJO is simple and already annotated.

DynamoDBMapper appears to be the object that will do a fetch to acquire the records and deserialize them into my POJOs. Perhaps using PaginatedScanList() to walk through the entire table.

Mapper's Scan() and PaginatedScanList() methods both require a DynamoDBScanExpression parameter. What DynamoDBScanExpression would be used to select all of the records in the table?

Comment: you can use a scan with an empty query expression

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can pass a `new DynamoDBScanExpression()` into the scan method.:

```
mapper.scan(MyObject.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
```

Or you could use the [new Document API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html)

Comment: Does 1 MB limit by DyanmoDB play's a role here?

Comment: @SHASHANKMADHAV No the returned list is of type PaginatedScanList.class, so under the hood pagination is being handled for you.